# Is there any way to force a WinUI 3 Datagrid to refresh (re-render) after the bound ItemsSource has changed?

Tags: datagrid, winui-3, maui-community-toolkit

1. I'm using the CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid control.
2. The ItemsSource property is bound to an ObservableCollection of objects.
3. These objects have a boolean-type property that I am binding checkboxes to.

The problem:
When a background operation changes the boolean value of some of the objects in the ObservableCollection, the datagrid doesn't reflect the new value (checkbox checked or not checked).

However, if I scroll the datagrid so the affected rows are no longer visible, then scroll back to the affected rows, the value is now rendered correctly.

So there is a work-around -- except for a datagrid that doesn't have enough rows to scroll.

Applicable Code:

```
<controls:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UiModel.Dictionary.Values}" CanUserReorderColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" PointerPressed="DataGrid_PointerPressed">
```

UIModel.Dictionary.Values definition:

```
IDictionary<string, ObservableCollection<MyClass<T>>>
```

The IDictionary is assigned an ObservableDictionary as defined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.iobservablemap-2?view=winrt-22621.

MyClass definition:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
public class MyClass<T> : ObservableObject
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public T Identifier { get; set; }
    private bool _selected;
    public bool Selected
    {
        get { return _selected; }
        set
        {
            _ = SetProperty(ref _selected, value);              
        }
    }
}
```

The DataTemplate binding:

```
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource CompactCheckbox}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=[0].Selected, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="0" />
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Adding **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** to the CheckBox binding doesn't help.

Also adding **Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** to the ItemsSource binding of the DataGrid doesn't help either.

Comment: My first guess is that you are not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. If you post code around ``UiModel.Dictionary.Values``, I might be able to help.

Comment: I've updated the question to include additional code.  INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented -- which I would suggest is demonstrated by the fact that the datagrid is binding to the changes;  it just isn't refreshing until it is forced to redraw.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is considered good practice, but I have solved this issue by calling the page's `InitializeComponent()`method again.

Try creating an event handler that contains something similar to:

```
public void RefreshGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _contentLoaded = false; // Reset page loaded status
    InitializeComponent();
    //Additional actions - I had to handle other events that were raised as 
    //a result of calling InitializeComponent() again here
}
```

Then, raise its event when your code changes the boolean value of any of your objects in your ObservableCollection.